# IDLE for Python - tracing only my variables in Debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, python-idle

I'd like to use IDLE's Debug mode to watch my variables. Unfortunately the Local and Global lists in the Debug window are filled with hundreds of classes, types and functions, which must be from importing pylab. This makes Debug difficult to use since I have to pick through a huge list to find my variables. Is there any way I can simply watch the dozen or so variables I've used in my program?
Many thanks.

**Update**
I took Terry's good advice and instead of `from pylab import *` I imported only the individual names the code needed. Now it is possible to watch the relevant variables during Debug.

Comment: How do you import pylab? I don't know the exact answer but it sounds like you used `import *` which is an anti pattern

Comment: Indeed I was guilty of using `from pylab import *`, thereby flooding the global assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not as you meant the question.

One thing on my list of improvements for Debugger is to suppress, by default, reserved **xyz** names so the the globals list starts empty and only shows names created by user code.

However, `import` is a disguised assignment statement and as fodma1 says, `import *` can flood globals with multiple assignments.  These are all names 'created with user code'.  So yes, you can avoid this.  If you don't want to type `pylab` over and over, abbreviate on input with `as P` or whatever.  Or just import the specific names you need if not too many.

I ran into this same issue yesterday trying to debug SO question code starting with `from tkinter import *`.  Len(tkinter.**dict**) == 165. (Fortunately, most begin with a Capital letter and the user's names did not.)